# How can I run a command for multiple files?

Tags: bash, linux, loop

I have a bunch of `.vcf` files in a folder and I want to run command below on all of them but doing that one by one manually is really painful. I am seeking for a way in terminal to do that simultaneously. The output would be a `.txt` file.

```
grep -v "##" /file.vcf | awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$2"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8"\t"$9"\t"$10"\t"$11}' > /file.txt
```

Can you help please?

Comment: Is the doubling of $2 intentional?  Seems like cut would be a little simpler to use here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming all your vcfs are in the same folder:

```
for file in *.vcf; do
    grep -v "##" ${file} | awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$2"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8"\t"$9"\t"$10"\t"$11}' > ${file}.txt
done
```

Answer (score 2):

If additional CPUs are available:

```
CPU_COUNT=5
for file in *.vcf; do 
     (grep -v "##" ${file} | awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$2"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8"\t"$9"\t"$10"\t"$11}' > ${file%.vcf}.txt) & let count+=1
     [[ $((count%CPU_COUNT)) -eq 0 ]] && wait
done
```

one-liner:

```
CPU_COUNT=5; for file in *.vcf; do (grep -v "##" ${file} | awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$2"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8"\t"$9"\t"$10"\t"$11}' > ${file%.vcf}.txt) & let count+=1; [[ $((count%CPU_COUNT)) -eq 0 ]] && wait; done
```